# Why does an Oracle join not use indexes when there is no where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I'm a long time Oracle user/developer. Oracle version is 19c.

The scenario is, I have a query which reads table A gets a unique identifier which joins to table B.

```
select A.unique_id, B.*
from A
inner join B on B.unique_id = A.unique_id
where A.unique_id = 123;
```

The query runs quickly and the explain plan shows it using B.unique_id's index.

If however I want to look at all rows like;

```
select A.unique_id, B.*
from A
inner join B on B.unique_id = A.unique_id;
```

It runs forever and the explain plan says it is doing a full table scan.

I am not clear what is happening. This seems to be a fundamental issue I must have missed.

Can someone explain;

1. Why it is behaving this way.
2. What I can do to force it to use the appropriate index. I tried index hint without success.

**Edit:**

Table A currently has ~7 million rows. Table B has ~28 million rows

Explain plan with where clause;

```html
<TABLE class="TreeTableWidget" border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100% bgcolor=#efefef><tr><td> 

 <!-- ..........................data begin...........................  -->

    <TABLE class=TreeTableWidget border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 align=center width=100%"  bgcolor=#ffffff> 
    <tr class="TableCell">

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#bbbbbb>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>OPERATION</font>&nbsp;</td>

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#aaaaaa>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>OBJECT_NAME</font>&nbsp;</td>

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#bbbbbb>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>OPTIONS</font>&nbsp;</td>

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#aaaaaa>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>CARDINALITY</font>&nbsp;</td>

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#bbbbbb>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>COST</font>&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>

   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-1><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/gray.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;SELECT STATEMENT&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf >&nbsp;1&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 >&nbsp;3&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-1><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/join.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;NESTED LOOPS&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf >&nbsp;1&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 >&nbsp;3&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/index.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;INDEX&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;IND_ABSGEOCODE&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;UNIQUE SCAN&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf >&nbsp;1&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 >&nbsp;2&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/index.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;INDEX&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;ABSHIST_RECORD_SEQ&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;UNIQUE SCAN&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf >&nbsp;1&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 >&nbsp;1&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
</table>

 <!-- ..........................data end...........................  -->

</td></tr></TABLE>
```

Explain plan without where clause;

```html
<TABLE class="TreeTableWidget" border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100% bgcolor=#efefef><tr><td> 

 <!-- ..........................data begin...........................  -->

    <TABLE class=TreeTableWidget border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 align=center width=100%"  bgcolor=#ffffff> 
    <tr class="TableCell">

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#bbbbbb>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>OPERATION</font>&nbsp;</td>

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#aaaaaa>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>OBJECT_NAME</font>&nbsp;</td>

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#bbbbbb>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>OPTIONS</font>&nbsp;</td>

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#aaaaaa>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>CARDINALITY</font>&nbsp;</td>

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#bbbbbb>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>COST</font>&nbsp;</td>

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#aaaaaa>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>OBJECT_NODE</font>&nbsp;</td>

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#bbbbbb>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>OTHER_TAG</font>&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>

   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-2><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/gray.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;SELECT STATEMENT&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;6787518&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;21297&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-2><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/gray.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;PX COORDINATOR&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-1><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/gray.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;PX SEND&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-2>&nbsp;SYS.:TQ10002&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-2>&nbsp;QC (RANDOM)&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;6787518&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;21297&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;:Q1002&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;P->S&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-1><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/join.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;HASH JOIN&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;BUFFERED&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;6787518&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;21297&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;:Q1002&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;PCWP&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-2><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/gray.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;PX RECEIVE&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;6930390&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;13149&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;:Q1002&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;PCWP&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-1><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/gray.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;PX SEND&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf ><font size=-2>&nbsp;SYS.:TQ10000&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 ><font size=-2>&nbsp;HYBRID HASH&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;6930390&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;13149&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;:Q1000&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;P->P&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-2><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/gray.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;STATISTICS COLLECTOR&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;:Q1000&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;PCWC&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-1><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/gray.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;PX BLOCK&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;ITERATOR&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;6930390&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;13149&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;:Q1000&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;PCWC&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-2><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/table.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;TABLE ACCESS&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;ABSHIST&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;FULL&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;6930390&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;13149&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;:Q1000&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;PCWP&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-2><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/gray.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;PX RECEIVE&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;6787518&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;8147&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;:Q1002&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;PCWP&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-1><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/gray.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;PX SEND&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-2>&nbsp;SYS.:TQ10001&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-2>&nbsp;HYBRID HASH&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;6787518&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;8147&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;:Q1001&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-2>&nbsp;PARALLEL_FROM_SERIAL&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-2><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/gray.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;PX SELECTOR&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;:Q1001&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 ><font size=-2>&nbsp;SINGLE_COMBINED_WITH_CHILD&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-1><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/index.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;INDEX&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-2>&nbsp;IND_ABSGEOCODE&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-2>&nbsp;RANGE SCAN&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;6787518&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-1>&nbsp;8147&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf ><font size=-1>&nbsp;:Q1001&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=7% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 ><font size=-2>&nbsp;SINGLE_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
</table>

 <!-- ..........................data end...........................  -->

</td></tr></TABLE>
```

Comment: A database uses a scan when it estimates that it's cheaper than a million of index lookups.

Comment: Where is:  1) Table DDL, 2) Index definitions, 3) output of explain plans?

Comment: @OldProgrammer The tables have lots of columns and a number indexes, but I added the explain plans the best I could. If you know a better way let me know. ABSHIST is "A" in my example and ABSGEOCODE is "B" in my example.

Comment: @PaulStearns The best way to investigate long-running queries is usually to generate a SQL Monitor Report. Find the relevant SQL_ID (query `V$SQL` if necessary) and then run this query: `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'YOUR SQL_ID here') from dual;` The output tells you what the real problem is (which operation is consuming the most time) and clues as to why the plan was chosen (by comparing estimated cardinality with actual cardinality). Normal explain plans only provide Oracle's *estimates* instead of the *actual* values needed to really investigate a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle will choose what it believes to be the best plan. Sometimes that will be using indexes, sometimes full table scans. So that's quite normal behavior, especially with the removal of a predicate. Given your current query without the 123 predicate, unless table_A is super tiny compared to table_B, a hash join with full scans is in fact the best method. You do *not* want to try to force it to use indexes.

As to why it's "taking forever", you should get an execution plan and query `v$active_session_history` for your SQLID to see what's going on and where it's spending time, or ask your DBA for help.

Without seeing anything, my initial guesses are:

1. The tables are huge and you are reading them in serial,
2. the tables are huge and it's having to work with a lot of temp space to do the join,
3. Since you are asking for all the rows to be returned to you client, perhaps they are in the process of being fetched, which can take a long time over your network to your client in little batches, but that's not the database's fault.
4. Maybe "taking forever" is relative, and you're wondering why you haven't seen the first row yet after a few minutes. That'd be because that's how a hash join works. It has to build the hash table from one input completely before starting to probe it with the other and only then will you start to see rows. What matter is overall run time for the entire SQL, not response time for the first row.

You can certainly get the hash join faster by employing parallelism:

```
select /*+ parallel(8) */ A.unique_id, B.*
from A
inner join B on B.unique_id = A.unique_id;
```

and perhaps also working with the DBA to allocate more PGA to reduce temp space workarea, but it won't do you  much good for overall run time because it'll take much longer to fetch all those results back to your client, and that's limited by your network latency and size of your client's fetch calls.

Comment: This is good information, but you might want to suggest a performance tuning tool better than directly querying `v$active_session_history`. While it's a useful view, I doubt the average Oracle user can successfully use it to troubleshoot performance issues. It might be better to recommend a specific query or ASH report. (Personally, I use SQL Monitor Reports, but I'm sure there are many similar tools.)

Comment: You are right, of course, but AWR/ASH,  reports are not that useful, and giving guidance on how to use v$active_session_history/v$sql_plan_monitor, etc.. properly would require a small class.  Tuning is simply too big a topic to address here. So I can only point them in the right direction if they want to dig deeper. I don't use any of this myself, as I wrote my own monitoring and visualization tool that I use predominately, but ASH data combined with the plan is available to all and pretty much the guts of what's needed to tackle most problems. Just querying/understanding it may be a barrier

Answer (score 0):

Another very common reason for Oracle not using an index is missing or stale database statistics.

Check when the tables and indexes has last been analysed using:

```
SELECT table_name, num_rows, last_analyzed FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'my_table';
```

and

```
SELECT index_name, num_rows, last_analyzed FROM user_indexes WHERE index_name = 'my_index';
```

If the statistics for the database objects you are are using are stale, you should force Oracle to generate new statistics with something like:

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SCOTT', 'EMPLOYEES', estimate_percent => 15, cascade => TRUE);
```

[Cost-Based Optimizer (CBO) And Database Statistics](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/cost-based-optimizer-and-database-statistics) offers a nice introduction before jumping into the official [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/tgsql/optimizer-statistics-concepts.html#GUID-C0E74ACE-2706-48A1-97A2-33F52207166A).

Comment: I checked the statistics and it had been a while so I ran the gather statistics with the same result.

Comment: Paul, please see my answer. Stats aren't going to help here. Given your query, Oracle will not use indexes and that's the right thing. Using indexes would make it *much* slower, if measured by overall throughput. Time to first output record is not what matters.

Comment: I would still not exclude the possibility that the statistics are not “perfect” but most likely Oracle now has made the decision not to use the index and the suggestions by Paul W should be followed.